# Preg_match_all PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
preg_match_all('#{news\s*(category\s*=\s*\"([0-9]+)\s*\")\s*(template\s*=\s*\"(.+?)\s*\")\s*}#is', $this, $array);
```

В регулярных выражениях совсем слаб, помогите пожалуйста.
Как написать условие, что бы была проверка на совпадение, т.е. может быть а может и не быть.
Например template="nnn" может быть, а может и не быть.

Сейчас если я убираю template="nnn" в строке, то вся функция просто не работает и не выбирает ничего. Как заставить её работать и передавать мне значения, даже если чего-то она не нашла?

Comment: `(template\s*=\s*\"(.+?)\s*\")?`

Comment: Спасибо большое, напишите в ответах - сделаю решённым.

Answer (score 1):

? - эквивалентен {0,1}

```
preg_match_all('#\{news\s*(category\s*=\s*\"([0-9]+)\s*\")?\s*(template\s*=\s*\"(.+?)\s*\")?\s*\}#is', $str, $array);
```